# Changing value of an index in pandas dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a series of dataframes in a dict.

```
type(mydict[0])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

print(dict[0])

          0         1         2
0  0.278735  0.609862  0.085823
1  0.836997  0.739635  0.866059
2  0.691271  0.377185  0.225146

print(dict[1])

          0         1         2
3  0.435280  0.700900  0.700946
4  0.796487  0.018688  0.700566
5  0.900749  0.764869  0.253200
```

How can I change the value of the index of `dict[1]` to such that it looks like this

```
print(dict[0])

          0         1         2
0  0.278735  0.609862  0.085823
1  0.836997  0.739635  0.866059
2  0.691271  0.377185  0.225146

print(dict[1])

          0         1         2
0  0.435280  0.700900  0.700946
1  0.796487  0.018688  0.700566
2  0.900749  0.764869  0.253200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
mydict[1].reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks This works on my simple example.  It unfortunately doesn't seem to work when dict[1] is a multiIndex dataframe with 2 levels where the index I'm trying to reset is at level=1.  I tried `for i in df: df[i] = self.data[i].reset_index(level=1, drop=True, inplace=True)`  but `print(mydict[1])` produces `None`  Good answer.  Over simplified example on my part.

Comment: inplace=True will make the function returning None. Don't assign the function result

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks.  Makes perfect sense.